# *ngIf directive in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I'm getting data from my backend server

```
proyecto: Proyecto;
ngOnInit(): void {
// subscribe START
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(
            params => {
                const id = params.get('id');
                console.log('MainContent:Proyecto Seleccionado: ', id);
                this.dataService.getDatosCabeceraProyecto(id)
                    .subscribe(
                        (data: Proyecto) => this.proyecto = data,
                        (err: any) => console.log(err),
                        () => console.log('MainContent: datos de proyecto recogidos')
                    );
            });
// subscribe END
}
```

But If I use ngIf directive I don't see anything

[image: html]

But I get the data

[image: console]

Any idea Please?
Thanks

Comment: Use can use this and check as example `<div *ngIf="!!proyecto">` also refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/784946/6923146

Comment: what you have written should work. I would add "data" to your console log to confirm what you are getting. `console.log(data);` It's possible this.proyecto is still null after your service completes.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking with some data inside the result with *ngIf and see if u get the results first .

For eg -

```
*ngIf="proyecto.ID==X000128"
```

This will give you an idea of what it accepts .

Comment: I get data correctly because I see them in console

Answer (score 0):

Use can use this and check as example

`<div *ngIf="!!proyecto">`

reference use of !!
Operator

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/784946/6923146